# Вывод не записыватеся в массив tg

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Как мне сделать запись переменной в массив keys.json. А то мой ключ записывается в "" единоразово. и обновляется постоянно при получении нового

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    const currentKeys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('keys.json'));
    const key = keygen();
    
    if (text === "/pay") {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, key)
        fs.writeFileSync('keys.json', JSON.stringify(key));
    }
```

Comment: и в keys.json сохраняет вот такой результат:
"7R0ST7uxk6v"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Доброе утро, я составил вроде понятный вопрос. У меня сохраняется результат в keys.json в кавычках и сохраняет только один вывод.

Comment: я помогу вам и уберу второй вопрос из текста вашего вопроса. пожалуйста, задайте этот второй вопрос отдельно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сделал

Comment: JSON как выглядит, значение `key` куда вписывать?

Comment: @Rudi "yjoYS90togh" . хотя ставлю []

Comment: @Rudi вывод в keys.json и в телеге один и тот же. т.е. все норм. просто у меня они не записываются ключи в массив